# Touching the 'C++' tag shows 'C' tagged questions

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app

When I touch the 'C++' tag in a question, the app displays a list of questions tagged with 'C', instead of the expected 'C++'.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Comment: @Cai Yes it's probably a duplicate. Feel free to close mine.